# Is this geometric series correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

There is an exercise with the following notation:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{2n}3x^{-n}
$$

Is this a correct notation?

According to the book the result of the calculation is 
$
3(2n+1)x^{-n}
$

How is it possible?

Comment: Usually, one would use $i$ in the exponent because $n$ is fixed in this problem.

Comment: Take the $3$ on the outside.  Now use the formula $$1 + a + \cdots + a^r = \frac{1 - a^{r+1}}{1-a}$$

Comment: I don't know how a geometric series can be correct.

Comment: It can be calculated in the way you wrote it but it's unusual to write it like this and is most likely a typo, where it was supposed to say $\sum_{i=0}^{2n}3x^{-i}$.

Comment: @D_S: The OP is asking whether the expression is well-formed.  As Michael Burr mentions, the summand should probably be $3x^{-i}$ or something like that—at any rate, probably not dependent on $n$, since that is not the index of summation.  Then it can be summed, using the formula you cite.

Comment: @BrianTung It should be made clear, though, that the expression *is* well-formed as it is too. It's just uncommon to write it like this.

Comment: This is almost certainly a typo.  In the most literal sense, however, it *can* be computed: since the value of the expression doesn't vary with the value of $i$, it would simply reduce to:

$$6nx^{-n}$$

Comment: @Wildcard You disappointed me!  There are $2n+1$ numbers from $0$ to $2n$, inclusively.  :D

Comment: @TimonG.: You are quite right.  I sort of skipped right past that in my comment.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, D'oh!  $(6n+3)x^{-n}$, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The calculation is correct, since we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{2n}3x^{-n}=3x^{-n}\sum_{i=0}^{2n}1=3x^{-n}(2n+1)
> \end{align*}

Here we use that $3x^{-n}$ does not depend on the summation index $i$ and we can apply the *[distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)*
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{2n}3x^{-n}&=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\left(3x^{-n}\cdot 1\right)=3x^{-n}\sum_{i=0}^{2n}1
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{a}1=a+1
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes of course! Thanks!

Comment: @Qualid: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The notation is valid, but it's probably not what you expect. To break down what's happening:

We are taking the sum from $i = 0$ to $i = 2n$ of some sequence $a_i$. In other words, we will look at the terms of the sequence $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{2n-1}, a_{2n}$ and add them together. There are a grand total of $2n+1$ terms.

The sequence is defined as $a_i = 3x^{-n}$. But $i$ doesn't actually appear in the expression, which means that *all terms of the sequence are equal*. The sequence is $\{3x^{-n}, 3x^{-n}, 3x^{-n}, \ldots\}$. So we are adding together $2n+1$ copies of $3x^{-n}$, so the total of the series is $(2n+1) \times 3x^{-n}$.

Now, it seems likely that there was a typo, and the intended sum was $\sum_{i=0}^{2n} 3x^{-i}$. In this case, the series looks like this (starting with the 0th term): $\{3, 3x^{-1}, 3x^{-2}, 3x^{-3}, \ldots\}$. So you start at $3$ and each successive term divides the previous one by $x$, or equivalently multiplies it by $x^{-1}$.

Then this is a geometric series with $2n+1$ terms, first term $3$ and ratio $x^{-1}$, and the sum is $3\left(\frac{1-x^{-(2n+1)}}{1-x^{-1}}\right)=3\frac{x-x^{-2n}}{x-1}$.

Comment: Interestingly, even with the typo (if that's what it is), formula denotes a geometric series; it's just a very boring series with ratio $1.$

Comment: True! Although one could also argue it's an arithmetic series with difference 0.

Comment: In fact it's both! :-)

Comment: @ConMan you are correct in your reasoning.